# Should I have multiple projects in a Solution or multiple Solutions for a console and web application that share same database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I currently have an asp.net console application which simply retrieves a lot of data via an API from a remote server and, using Entity Framework, saves it into an SQL database.  The application takes 3-4 days to run and I run it manually once a month or so.

The project is separated into a Models class, and a Repository class as well as the application itself.

I need to now build an ASP.NET MVC web application which allows users to view the data that has been retrieved and am looking for advice on how best to structure this.

Do I create a new ASP.NET MVC project in my solution and set that as the start up application, referencing the same Models and Repository classes? If so, how do I then run my console app?  Or is it best to keep these as separate solutions, just referencing the same database?

Is there a better way of doing this as well? (ie, is there some way the console application can be rebuilt as being part of the front end and use queues or workers to fetch the data regularly?)

Thanks for your help,
Robbie.

Comment: I'd do it in the same solution if I were you, since that promotes code reuse. Put your models and repository in a separate class library in the solution.

Comment: Surely it would be better to move the shared code into a separate class library and just reference that between the two solutions?

Comment: I see you accepted JoeMighty's answer, but Chris Pratt's is much better reasoned. Why did you accept that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would keep these as separate projects and separate solutions that just reference the same database, but move code that can be shared by both solutions into a separate class library.

The way your web application will present your modeled the data will most likely be very different to how your console application will use it; so using the same models and repositories will most likely further couple your web application to your console application.

This is very similar to the way micro services work, where the micro service acts and grows independent of its consumers (in this instance, your web application) and only communicate via a clearly defined *API*.

Comment: The models shouldn't be very different, at least the *domain models*, since you're dealing with the same information. *View models* on the other hand may be different if those are being used.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster, I missed that!

Answer (score 6):

Same solution. Different projects. By being in the same solution you gain the easy ability to reference shared components. I would actually recommend breaking out your entities, repositories, etc. into a third project, a class library, that then both your console app and MVC app will reference.

If you don't put everything in the same solution, then you're either stuck in DLL hell, where you have to build your project and manually copy the DLL into the other project, add the reference, and then keep everything up to date when you make changes in that DLL. The more projects that get involved, the greater the entropy and greater the likelihood that your projects all end up running on different versions of the DLL.

Another option is to create a Nuget package containing the shared components, host it in your own private repo, and then add it to each project that needs it. However, while it's pretty easy to set all this up, it's not 100% frictionless, and you will have to remember to repackage and republish the Nuget whenever you make changes, and then individually update the package in each referencing project.

Long and short, same solution is always the best way to go unless there's a very good reason not to. It's the only "it just works" approach.

Comment: I generally use this setup too for ease of shared referencing. With the MVC project as the startup application, you can still right-click the Console App, then choose Debug>Start New Instance to run this.